# Warning on comparing a SmallInt with result of Ord function

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe7

I'm comparing a `SmallInt` variable with the result of the `Ord` function.
Example:

```
var
  MySmallInt : SmallInt;
begin
  MySmallInt := 5;
  if(MySmallInt > Ord('C'))
  then ShowMessage('True')
  else ShowMessage('False');
end
```

After doing this, the following warning message is shown ([W1023](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/W1023_Comparing_signed_and_unsigned_types_-_widened_both_operands_(Delphi))):

> W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands

Delphi's hint on the `Ord` function says that it should return a `SmallInt` and that's why I can't understand what causes the warning message. (I've looked for `Ord` function in the `System` unit but I didn't find it).

[image]

**Further Informations:**

- I'm testing under Delphi XE7.
- Under Delphi 2007, the same code doesn't give me any warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As David said, `Ord()` is a so called "compiler magic" (or, as they call it now, "intrinsic" or "pseudo-") function, i.e. not a real function that is called, but just something that uses a function syntax, but is recognized by the compiler as a special construct and turned into code directly. The same is true for e.g. `Chr()`, `Writeln()`, etc. They can usually have different and/or multiple types of parameters or return values and sometimes even have additional syntax elements.

The documentation says, about `Ord(X)`:

> The result is the ordinal position of X; its type is the smallest standard integer type that can hold all values of X's type.

In Delphi XE7, `'C'` is a `WideChar`, and the return value of `Ord('C')` will be a 16 bit *unsigned* type (`Word`). `Smallint` is *signed* type. That is why you get the warning, *because you are comparing a signed and an unsigned type of the same size, so the values must be widened to the next larger type (`Integer`)*.

In Delphi 2007, `'C'` is not a `WideChar`, it is an `AnsiChar`, so the result of `Ord('C')` is a `Byte`. There is no need for widening to the next larger type, since `Smallint` can contain all values of `Byte`, so both can be promoted to `Smallint`.

---

*I agree that the info hint in the editor is deceptive. `Ord()` does not always return a `Smallint`, it returns the minimum type that is needed to hold all values of the argument.*

Answer (score 2):

`Ord()` is an intrinsic function that yields an unsigned type. Hence the warning. In your case, you are passing it a `WideChar`, and so the matching integral type is `Word`.