# Which type returns System.Ord when passing a Char as parameter?

Tags: delphi, types, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe7

In Delphi 2007 projects, I am using [`System.Ord`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Ord.html) function as follows:

```
var
  Tmp : SmallInt;
begin
  Tmp := Ord('A');

  if(Tmp = Ord('A')) then
    ShowMessage('A');
end;
```

The same code under Delphi XE7 causes the following compiler warning message:

> [dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(31): W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned
>   types - widened both operands

The hint tells that it returns a `Smallint`

[image]

I found that the [`System.Ord` documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Ord.html) states:

> X is a Delphi ordinal-type expression. The result is the ordinal
>   position of X; its type is the smallest standard integer type that can
>   hold all values of X's type.
>
> Ord cannot operate on Int64 values.

Which is the returned type when passing a Char as parameter in Delphi XE7?

Comment: Effectively it is likely a 16-bit unsigned integer (`Word = UInt16`). That would explain the warning. (`SmallInt = Int16` is a 16-bit *signed* integer.)

Comment: It seems that I was already falled into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288051/warning-on-comparing-a-smallint-with-result-of-ord-function) some years ago. I cannot delete the question but It's exactly the same I've asked 2 years ago

Answer (score 1):

Characters in Delphi XE7 are of the type `WideChar`. But in Delphi 2007, they are `AnsiChar`.

So, following are the return types of `Ord('A')` in each version:

Delphi XE7   - Word

Delphi 2007  - Byte

Now when you try to assign the Ord('A') to a SmallInt in Delphi XE7, the compiler warns - because the return type of the function is unsigned and what you try to assign it to is a signed type.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294958/4185234) answer for more details about the behavior of the `Ord()` pseudo function

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the ordinal ranges of the `Char` type using [`Low`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Low.html) and [`High`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_High.html) functions:

```
  ShowMessage(
    'Low = ' + IntToStr(Ord(Low(Char))) + sLineBreak +
    'High = ' + IntToStr(Ord(High(Char)))
  );
```

**On Delphi2007**, it produces:

> Low = 0
>
> High = 255

So I could optimize my code and use `Byte` instead of `Smallint`.

**On Delphi XE7**, it produces:

> Low = 0
>
> High = 65535

So the result should be a `Word`

Comment: That's because `Char` is Unicode in Delphi 2009 and later. While an ansi char is one byte, a wide char is 2 bytes (a word).